# Axis positioning for Accel/Mag/Gyro on movesense device

Tags: movesense

What is the axis layout on the movesense for the Accel/Mag/Gyro sensors?  is there a diagram somewhere that I missed?  For example, is Z coming directly out of the top of the device, and then -Z coming out the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from the Movesense application, mobile application and move the device around:

```
positive x-axis is to the right while wearing it
positive y-axis is downwards while wearing
positive z-axis is through the device
```